# How return output in local machine from socat command linux

Tags: linux, socat

I have an up and running service ( is an emulated machine or something similar ) on my local Ubuntu machine and i'm able to access it through a serial port and following socat command:

```
> sudo socat file:`tty`,raw,escape=0x1d,echo=0 unix-connect:/tmp/sample-serial
root@sample:~#
```

I exit from the service and with the following socat command i can execute the bash file ( is in local machine ) to this service.

```
> sudo socat file:my_bash_script.sh unix-connect:/tmp/sample-serial
```

If i enter again with the first socat command in the service i can see my_bash_script.sh output going on in the service terminal

The question is: how i can see the output of this my_bash_script.sh from local machine?
Consider that in the service, socat command not exist then i can't open a TCP connections or similar.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the second command, the file: address appends the command output to the script. Try something like

> sudo socat file:my_bash_script.sh!!- unix-connect:/tmp/sample-serial

to get command output on your terminal.

Please note that '!' may substitute part of the command line with some terminal history, type

> set +H

to turn this behaviour off.

Comment: sudo socat file:my_bash_script!!- unix-connect:/tmp/sample-serial don't return to console the output, i don't see it even with -d -d and -v arguments. Maybe could be a problem of "wait a response", i have tried sudo socat -v -t500 file:my_bash_script!!- unix-connect:tmp/sample-serial and i have seen for really short time some output to console ( only one time )

Comment: For me the following works on a single host:
Terminal 1:
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/sample-serial EXEC:bash; 

Terminal 2:
echo "ls /" >/tmp/ls.sh; socat FILE:/tmp/ls.sh!!- UNIX:/tmp/sample-serial

Comment: In a single host i can say it work but is not so true that i have a single host. It's like i have two hosts: one is the local, the second is a sort of service in the local host where i can log into. sudo socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/sample-serial EXEC:bash give me following message: E /tmp/sample-serial exists, and this not permit me to listen. 
socat -V = socat version 1.7.3.3 on Oct 26 2019 17:42:04

Comment: Try address option `unlink-early` to remove left over socket on start: `socat ... UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/sample-serial,unlink-early ...`

Comment: The problem is more complicated of that i think, by investigating more the service where i unix-connect is a QEMU Node where a serial port is created with command qemu_system --serial tmp/sample-serial-serial,server,nowait or something like that.

Then, after i have create this QEMU Node with a provided private script in bash, the serial port is up and i need to us it from local machine to connect to this node. If i delete it with unlink-early, i delete the serial port and then i can't use it anymore.

Comment: Investigating more on socat command i have found a possible solution. sudo socat -v -T10 file:my_bash_script.sh,ignoreeof unix-connect:/tmp/sample-serial. I execute the my_bash_script.sh into this QEMU node via sample-serial as before. Because of ignoreeof from file side, the connection is not closed immediately and i can "listen" from serial-sample console what is happening. I'm currently appending the output of the bash script and also the execution of it from QEMU node in the my_bash_script.sh locally. After 10 seconds of inactivity, the connection to sample-serial is closed.